# Remove the function after it being used for the first time

Tags: javascript, builder

I have the simple SQL query builder that looks like this:

```
class QueryBuilder {
  select(fields) {
    this.query = "SELECT `" + fields.join("`, `") + "` ";
    return this;
  }

  from(table) {
    this.query += "FROM `" + table + "` ";
    return this;
  }
}
```

The problem is that it returns `this` so I'm able to do like:

```
const sql = builder.select("field1", "field2").from("table").select("I shouldn't be able to call select");
```

Is there any way to disable/remove the `select` function from `Builder` instance and autocomplete after calling it for the first time? Or to underscore that calling that function for the second time will cause an error.

**Solution:**

According to @Sohail answer, to make it works like that you just need to move `from()` from the `QueryBuilder` class and just return it as a field with the query as a new plain object:

```
class QueryBuilder {
  static select(fields) {
    this.query = "SELECT `" + fields.join("`, `") + "` ";
    return {
      query: this.query,
      from
    };
  }
}

function from(table) {
  this.query += "FROM `" + table + "` ";
  return {
    query: this.query,
    where: function() {}
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the specific `method` instead of `this`, that could be called in chain after this method.

**Example:**

```
class QueryBuilder {
  select(fields) {
    this.query = "SELECT `" + fields.join("`, `") + "` ";
    return {
      from: this.from.bind(this)
    };
  }
  from(table) {
    this.query += "FROM `" + table + "` ";
    return {
      where : ""
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Is then a way to "not let me" call `from()` before `select()`? Or I just need to move it out from `QueryBuilder` class?

**upd:** removing it from the class works. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You could make other methods private and make only select method public,  but the private syntax is a new feature in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below modification:

```
select(fields) {
    if(!this.query.includes("SELECT")){
       this.query = "SELECT `" + fields.join("`, `") + "` ";
    }
    return this;
  }
```

Comment: Then I'm still able to use select through autocomplete

Comment: use boolean flag and set true in the first call and check the same boolean in the second call if the flag is true just return don't do anything.